# XML to Flat File using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.5

I am using XMLDocumnet to create the XML file. But for the interface, I need to share them as the flat file.
Please help.

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            string loadFilePath = Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\IC35181.xml");
            doc1.Load(loadFilePath);

doc1.Save(Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\IC35181.xml"));

File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\IC35181.xml"), Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\IC35181_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_0" + (++k).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ".xml"), true);

doc1.DocumentElement.ParentNode.RemoveAll();
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\IC35181.xml"), string.Empty);
File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~\\XMLRootTag.xml"),Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\IC35181.xml"), true);
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting

Comment: Not getting error, I am getting formatted XML but I need Flat XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to control the formatting, then instead of using `XmlDocument.Save(string path)`, use `XmlDocument.Save(XmlWriter w)` - you'll have to create your own `XmlWriter` via `XmlWriter.Create(string, XmlWriterSettings)`, i.e.

```
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Server.MapPath("~\\temp\\IC35181.xml"), yourSettings))
{
    doc1.Save(writer);
}
```

Then all we need is to decide what format settings to put in your `XmlWriterSettings` instance (`yourSettings` in the example). Perhaps:

```
var yourSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = false,
    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None,
    NewLineOnAttributes = false,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Marc answer also work for me but I found one more property which work for me as well:

```
doc1.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```